# clang compiler warnings Mac OS X

Tags: macos, clang, clang++

When I compile my program I get compiler warnings. I have been trying to fix them for a while now.

This is how I compile:

```
c++ -MM -MF obj/src/prog.d -MP -MT obj/src/prog.o -Wall -Wextra -c -g -Iinc src/prog.cpp
```

This is the warning I get:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-MF obj/src/prog.d'
```

I used to compile it without warnings before apple switched to clang. right now c++ is just a symbolic link to clang.

I was wondering if smbd had the same kind of issue?

Any ideas?

Thanks

---

hmm... it seems like it is a bug(or feature): [link](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2010-October/015089.html).

But I think I found a work-around, instead of using MF to specify the output file, I just redirect it to the file like this:

```
c++ -MM > obj/src/prog.d -MP -MT obj/src/prog.o -Wall -Wextra -c -g -Iinc src/prog.cpp
```

Comment: and dependencies are not generated...

Comment: Not tried, but with the -Xpreprocessor _arg_ you can pass _arg_ to the preprocessor in clang.